# How to Make Joints in Mesh? Distorts when I rotate in pose mode

Tags: mesh, pose-mode

[image: Hoof of a deer character mesh I've been trying to get right, but keep messing up.]
 See how that part of the mesh distorts when I rotate The hoof bone? I'm trying to figure out why it's doing that and what I can do to fix it. From my understanding, it should be properly rigged to that part of the mesh, but I am new to blender, so I could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

are your mesh and armature both at the correct scale? in object mode if you Ctrl+A (apply) you can apply scale which keeps any transformations but neutralizes its scale in interactions, which can be the cause of some of these distortion problems.

Also, for future reference, for questions like this it can be helpful to upload your .blend along with the question.